# Getting an ordered hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model as follows

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base

  named_scope :from_affiliate_id, Proc.new { |id|
    { :select => "COUNT(*) as count_all, date(created_at) as date_created_at",
      :conditions => {:affiliate_id => id},
      :group => "date(created_at)",

    }
  }
  named_scope :in_dates, Proc.new {|from,to|{ :conditions => ["date(created_at) >= ? and date(created_at) <= ?",from,to]}}

  belongs_to :affiliate

  def self.create_quote(value = '')
    return if value.nil?
    quote = self.new(:affiliate_id => value)
    quote.save
  end

end
```

When I do Quote.from_affiliate_id(1), I get the following result

```
[#<Quote >, #<Quote >, #<Quote >, #<Quote >]
```

I want to get an ordered Hash instead. Which should have a date as a key and count as value. Please help me with it. Thanking in an anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Quote.from_affiliate_id(1).inject({}) do |h,q|
  h[q.created_at] = q.count_all
  h
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ActiveSupport::OrderedHash[*Quote.from_affiliate_id(1).map {|q|
  [q.created_at, q.count_all]
}.flatten]
```

Creating a normal hash will not be ordered:

```
>> ActiveSupport::OrderedHash[4,3,2,1].to_a
=> [[4, 3], [2, 1]]
```

vs.

```
>> Hash[4,3,2,1].to_a
=> [[2, 1], [4, 3]]
```